# Microsoft Access forms & Microsoft Windows Application

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, windows

I wanted to find a way to use forms created in Microsoft Access in a Windows Form Application (C#). After searching the net, I succeeded to open an Access database which automatically shows the form that i want using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access`:

```
Access.Application acApp = new Access.Application();
acApp.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\My_DataBase.mdb", true);
acApp.Visible = true;                
acApp.DoCmd.OpenForm("My Access Form");
//acApp.Quit();
```

This opens the Access form in separate window, is there a way to merge it with the Windows Application form?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no. To interpret and execute an Access Form, you need an Access instance. Your code won't work even in present form, in a computer without Access or Access runtime installed. And Access, as a separate application, will always create a separate window. I don't see any way around it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I don't mind that there will be a need to install Access or Access runtime to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

you may create a 'not-so' endless loop.
1)on access 'close' event create a file with
all the information data-entered\calculated 
in ms-access
2)in the meantime, in c#, run a loop that 
breaks only when the file is found. 
Then, extract from the file all info 
your access has to contribute to your pproject!
and...that's the way applications can run 'as modal'